# Accessing localStorage in an iframe

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm loading this HTML from a different domain into an IFRAME:

```
<script>
console.log(localStorage);
localStorage.setItem('test', 'test');
console.log(localStorage);
</script>
```

This seems to work fine in Chrome and Edge. In Firefox however I get:

> SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

What's going on here?

Comment: Maybe you can work around this issue by reassigning the localStorage object used in your script:

`var localStorage = unsafeWindow.localStorage;`

Comment: Does the `iframe` have the `sandbox` attribute enabled on it?

Comment: @frankenapps The problem is not that localStorage cannot be found. The problem seems to be that it cannot be accessed. So I don't see how your suggestion would work.

Comment: @rvighne No, there's no sandbox attribute. Good call though!

Comment: @rvighne Hang on! The sandbox attribute isn't set in the HTML but in the DOM I see an empty DOMTokenList. Does that mean all restrictions apply? I'm confused now...

Comment: If it looks like `<iframe src="..." sandbox>` (i.e. with an empty sandbox attribute), then yes, all restrictions apply and it explains your problem. Otherwise, (no sandbox attribute at all), then there are no restrictions

Comment: @rvighne Well, there's no sandbox attribute in the HTML - as I said - but could it have been added with JavaScript? And if so, would it look like an empty DOMTokenList? Or does an empty DOMTokenList mean there's no sandbox attribute at all?

Comment: The empty list could mean that either the attribute isn't set, or that it is set but not given a value. So the list being empty does not tell you whether the frame is sandboxed at all or not